# Determine if 3 parametric curves have same plot

Tags: parametric, curves

I have to determine if those three parametric curves have the same plot:

$\gamma_1(t) = (\cos(t), \sin (t))$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$

$\gamma_2(t) = (\cos(t), \sin (t))$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$

$\gamma_3(t) = (\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2})$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$

I don't have any idea on how to resolve this, checked several times on my lessons but I don't get how to calculate parametric plot. Any help (not answer of course, I want to understand this question :)) please?

Comment: $\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_2(t)$ it is made out of of periodic functions. (You should write it down more formal...) $\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_3(t)$ because of the t-formulas. (once again this needs formal proof)

Comment: I don't understand "formal", what do you mean (I'm French, sorry)?

Comment: "Une démonstration formelle" ;), it's not 'very' mathematical to write '$\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_2(t)$ because it is made out of periodic functions'...

Comment: Oh yeah I misread. Of course I wasn't gonna write that :p! Thanks.

Comment: @dietervdf I've been trying to write it down "more formal" but don't really get to anything :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that both $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are unit circles centered in the origin. The difference is that $\gamma_1$ just goes around once, while $\gamma_3$ go on and on. And you can check that the trace of $\gamma_3$ is contained in the unit circle by checking that the functions $x(t) = (1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$ and $y(t) = 2t/(1+t^2)$ satisfy the relation $$x(t)^2+y(t)^2 = 1.$$
(familiar?)

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense in my head now. Thanks, I know where to go now, it's clearer!

Comment: Well it definitely gives a circle but the $\gamma_3$ has no solution on -1. The point doesn't exist. http://tinyurl.com/pan5ujm So it doesn't seem to work but I think my problem is with the $\mathbb{R}$. Since it's a much larger interval, the plot is indeed the same, am I right? (some friends made me wondering that)

Comment: Can I use limit on $t \to \infty, \gamma_3 \to -1$ to prove that this is the same plot?

Comment: Well, $\gamma_3 \to -1$ does not makes sense. What does it mean to a curve go to a point? Checking $x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 = 1$ proves that the plot is contained in the circle. Now you have to take a point in the circle and prove that exists $t_0$ s.t. the point is exactly $\gamma_3(t_0)$. This is quite a pain to do, so I'll tell you the trick: the motivation for the parametrization of $\gamma_3$ is indeed using that $\sin^2+\cos^2 = 1$. A point in the circle is of the form $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. Write that $\cos \theta = (1-t_0^2)/(1+t_0^2)$ and $\sin \theta = 2t_0/(1+t_0^2)$. Find $t_0$.

Comment: Ok thanks I figured it out :).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. What is different about $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$?  Does this difference change how the plot looks?  Why or why not?  (Bonus hint:  Don't let your head spin around in **circle**s.)
2. The curve $\gamma_3$ is more different, but the main question is this:  Do the reals map to the same locus of points as the other two functions?

Comment: For $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ it doesn't change because sin and cos are defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$ => period $2\pi$. For $\gamma_3$ it's still cos and sin with t as a function. So it should maps the same locus of points.

Answer (score 1):

All three plots are the same. The first two are simply the parametrization of the unit circle by trigonometric functions with period $2\pi$. The last one is a rational parametrization of the unit circle.